# Putting data into a table using dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am attempting to build a table that will operate agnostically of the data I'm submitting to it. Meaning that I will pass it a JSON object(in the future, right now I'm just passing it a couple of arrays to test) and it will form the appropriate columns and rows according to the object. What I'm wanting to do is take the elements in the headers array and form my columns and take the elements in the data array and form my rows. I built a couple ng-repeat to handle looping through the objects but when my chart forms, nothing is in it(I'll provide a screenshot). Any ideas why my table isn't working?
Here is my code for my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<div >
    <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="header in headers">
                <h2>{{header}}</h2>
            </td>                      
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="dp of data">
            <td ng-repeat="header in headers">
                {{dp[header]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
  `,
  styles: [`
  table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TestTable';
    headers = [{column:"ID",name:"Name"}];
    data = [
            {id:1,name:"Tony"},
            {id:2,name:"Zach"},
            {id:3,name:"Scot"},
        ];    
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here's my errors but I don't think they're the reason it's not working(I could be wrong though:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In angular 2 you need to use ng-for instead of ng-repeat.
Just add this before headers and data. Hope it will work for you.

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(){
  this.title = 'TestTable';
    this.headers = [{column:"ID",name:"Name"}];
    this.data = [
            {id:1,name:"Tony"},
            {id:2,name:"Zach"},
            {id:3,name:"Scot"},
        ];    
  };
}
```

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vThJke2UfwRDPHNV1oWq?p=preview) link.
Thanks . Let me know if you have any other query.

Comment: That caused it to fail to compile because it expected a constructor

Comment: Hey @Joris I have updated the comment. Please check it . I think now you dont get this error anymore now.

Comment: That breaks it as well. I don't think you're allowed to use that `constructor()` within the AppComponent class

Comment: Hi I have again updated the my answer and also given a plunker link . Just have a look. I ho[pe this time you will get an answer. If this work, then mark it as answer.